MS Graph account mailbox settings mail auto forwarding (C#)
Is there any way to set the mailbox auto forwarding using graph api or sdk?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-on-automatic-forwarding-in-outlook-7f2670a1-7fff-4475-8a3c-5822d63b0c8e
well i know a similar question asked 2years ago.
However, it's 2024 now. Is it still not possible?

Yes, it's still not possible to set the mailbox auto forwarding using Graph API. You can upvote this idea here https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/graph-api-manage-mailbox-forwarding/idi-p/3928970

Yes, it's still not possible to set the mailbox auto forwarding using Microsoft Graph API.
You can upvote this idea here techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/…
Alternatively, make use of below PowerShell command by connecting Exchange Online to enable auto forwarding of user's mailbox:
Connect-ExchangeOnline
Set-Mailbox -Identity "sri@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com" -ForwardingSmtpAddress "user@xxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"

Response:

This enabled mailbox auto forwarding when I checked user's Outlook like this:


Is there a way to remove it as well? won't accept NULL or empty string and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailbox?view=exchange-ps doesn't show another good candidate
